# What does it "they like me for me" mean?

Tags: colloquial-language

What does the following mean?

> They like me for me.

I have never seen this expression before.

Comment: You say you've never seen the expression before, but you probably have, or you wouldn't be asking this question. It would be better to edit the question and tell us where you heard it or saw it.

Comment: Originally, it was "I never saw it before", I thought it didn't make sense so I changed it to "I have never seen it bofore". Would "I never saw it before" make more sense? If yes, I will edit it back.

Answer (score 2):

It means people like you the way that you are and they don't want you to change they like the real you like you're not pretending to be something that you're not it's a compliment

Comment: it may also mean they like you as a person and not because you have lots of money or because you are attractive or you could get them a job or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

(I originally posted this as a comment to the more-recently-asked [What does “like someone for someone” mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253611/what-does-like-someone-for-someone-mean), which was closed as a duplicate.)

---

The cited text ***is not idiomatic*** (except insofar as it's "deliberately quirky" because of the way it uses ***me*** twice in proximity with different meanings). People sometimes use reflexive pronouns in such contexts *(I want you to love me for **myself**, Maybe she'll like us for **ourselves**)*, but even that isn't really clear enough.

Usually it'll be expressed more explicitly - for example...

> *I want you to love me for **myself, not my wealth***
> *Maybe she'll like us for **who we are.***